# How can I improve my LIKE with JOIN search in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join, search, sql-like

I currently have a search that looks like this:

```
SELECT s.ID 
    FROM Shoe s
        INNER JOIN Account a
            ON s.UserID = a.ID
        WHERE s.Publish='1' AND
            (s.Brand LIKE '%$Search%'
             OR s.Name LIKE '%$Search%'
             OR s.PrimaryColor LIKE '%$Search%'
             OR a.User LIKE '%$Search%') 
        ORDER BY s.ID DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage"
```

This works fine when I do a search such as "Blue" or "Nikes", but if I do a search such as "Blue Nikes" nothing returns. Should I use `FULLTEXT`? How can I improve this? I want to be able to search all columns that may relate to the search variable.

Comment: Yes, you should use MySQL's full text search capabilities or an external search index.

Comment: Using wildcards on the left of the LIKE will prevent MySQL from using the index.  Depending on your needs, you might also look at something like solr.

Comment: @SeanBright I tried using Match Against with Fulltext and got zero results. I further search this and came across this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925369/mysql-join-and-match-against-search-fail seems that it won't work because of "stop" words. I'm not too advance on mysql so forgive me if I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after messing around and testing different things, I came up with this:

```
"FROM Shoe AS s
    LEFT JOIN Accounts AS a ON s.UserID = a.ID
    WHERE (MATCH (s.Brand, s.Name, s.PrimaryColor AGAINST('$Search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        OR MATCH (a.User) AGAINST('$Search' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
            AND s.Publish='1'
    ORDER BY s.ID DESC"
```

This seems to fix my issue that I mentioned above, I can now do a search such as "Blue Nike" and all items related to blue & nike will show up. Not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about it, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LIKE` try using [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex), or both.

Secondly, you may want to optimize the query to maintain capitalization, for example:

```
(lower(s.Brand) LIKE '%" . strtolower($Search) . "%'
OR lower(s.Name) LIKE '%" . strtolower($Search) . "%'
OR lower(s.PrimaryColor) LIKE '%" . strtolower($Search) . "%'
OR lower(a.User) LIKE '%" . strtolower($Search) . "%')
```

Comment: So at the top should it be something like this `SELECT s.ID, SOUNDEX(s.Brand), SOUNDEX(s.Name), SOUNDEX(s.PrimaryColor), SOUNDEX(a.User) FROM Shoe s...`?

Comment: Something like this: SELECT * FROM shoe AS s WHERE (s.Name SOUNDS LIKE 'Nike' OR s.Name LIKE 'Nike%');

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but I didn't improve the results. If I search a brand I got results, if I search a color nothing shows.

Comment: It won't solve your problem completely, but it may improve the search with additional optimizations. Search can get very complicated and a simple SQL statement won't do it all the time. Consider using auto-complete, like how this site does for searching by tag.